# Split Android Textview

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview that reads 4:14. I need to grab the hour 4, and the minute, 14, from it. The problem is the colon makes it a string so I cant get the numbers as ints, how Would I get just The 4 and the 14 without the colon separately from the textview. Thanks.

The value is set by user so it might not always be 4:14. That was just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String temp = "4:14";
String[] str_array = temp.split(":");

String hour = str_array[0]; 
String minute = str_array[1];
minute = minute.replace(" AM","");
minute = minute.replace(" PM","");


int hourInt = Integer.parseInt(hour);
int minuteInt = Integer.parseInt(minute);
```

hope it will help :)

Comment: sorry i forgot it would be either 4:14 PM or 4:14 AM. The hour works in your code but minute does not

Comment: Do you always have two digit minute integer in your code ?

Comment: yes I do even if it is less then 10 it will be 03 for example

Comment: It worked but because there is a space between 14 and PM like this 4:14 PM. I had to add the code minute = minute.replace(" ","")

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
String[] hoursAndMinutes = yourString.split(":");
```

And you get table of your numbers.

- in hoursAndMinutes[0] - hours
- in hoursAndMinutes[1] - minutes

Simply change it into ints. Like this:

```
int hour = Integer.parseInt(hoursAndMinutes[0]);
int minutes = Integer.parseInt(hoursAndMinutes[1]);
```